# How do I mention my own small online business in my resume?

Tags: resume

How do I mention my own small online retail business(B2C) in my resume? I have been working on it for the past 5 months and it has grown to generate a revenue of around 4k a month (projecting at 48k a year) and the monthly revenue is steadily growing. My partner and I do everything for the business, from sourcing/operations to sales to marketing.

I intend to run it on the sideline as it is now fully automated (I have hired someone to take care of it, I only manage it now).

How do I mention building this business in my resume as experience/skill? I am looking at a job in B2B sales / trading / B2B or retail marketing .

Answer (score 8):

> Date X - present        **Clown Shoes for Dogs.COM**        *Owner*
>
> Duties: Sourcing clown shoe manufacturer, sizing dogs feet, counting the money,  building network within dog clown community, blah, blah, blah
>
> Accomplishments: Turned niche market idea from concept to profitable self sustaining business, award from local clown college, blah, blah,...

Your duties and accomplishments are going to be much more important than your title so focus on what you did in your role as owner especially things that can be interpreted as transferable skills.

Comment: Nice short answer to a difficult question